# android - How to capture photo By click volume up key?

Tags: android, bluetooth, camera, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I want to develop app using Bcoda Wheel Device.

In this app I want to capture photo using key up(Volume up).

But I am not getting inbuilt camera key up listener in my app.

In my app camera capture coding is not integrate. My app just pass the Volume up key press intent via broadcast or anything.

1) Start camera (In built app).
2) My app call volume up key press using receiver.
3) Bluetooth Bcoda Device pressed and clicked photo (Same as wear or some bluetooth device).

My app work as a intermediate.

**Edit:**

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();


                try {
                    Process process = r.exec("input keyevent 24");
                    InputStream stream = process.getErrorStream();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
```

I tried this code Vol+ Button work when My app in Foreground But when apps goes in Background Mode. This code execute in background but Vol+ button not working.

Help resolve this issue.

Thanks